# Automate Update with script ( Flash, Java, Reader )

Tags: windows-7, script, flash, updates, automated-builds

I'm deploying over 10-20 computers every week and have to update each computer manually. 
Is there a script that I could use that:
 **Checks-Version,**
 **Downloads-New-Version,** 
 **Updates-New-Version**.
I cant install any 3rd party software because these computers need to be as clean as possible.
I have found scripts that install the offline versions of flash/Java but that means re-downloading the update after every new release.
Whats my options?

Edit: I could use 3rd part tools as long as I dont have to install the software on the computer. (Portable-Software)

Comment: This capability does not exist in Windows out of the box.  This means what you want cannot be done without the use of third-party software.  This feature likely will never be added since all those programs you list are not features of Windows itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ninite Pro](https://ninite.com/pro) and you can push those installs to the machine from remote over the network. It's also portable so you can just throw the EXE on a machine, use it to do the installs/updates and then delete it (no install/uninstall).

> We designed Ninite Pro to make your life easier and fit in with your workflow. Whether you just want to make sure your PCs are secure and up-to-date, or if you're a repair tech, IT professional, or managed service provider, Ninite Pro can help you work faster and better.

It will install the latest version if it's not installed, or will upgrade to the latest. You can also use it to uninstall the programs and audit the computers for the software packages it covers. Additionally you can specify if the icons should be created on the desktop and if Auto-update in the programs should be enabled or not.

We use it here and it's handy dandy.

I have it scripted out in our domain updating Java Adobe Reader and a few others at each boot of the computers and haven't had to touch a machine to install or update those programs in over a year now. :)

The time it has saved is well worth low price they ask for Pro.

Comment: See the problem with using this service would be the HUGE price tag. If im deploying 10-20 machines a week then ill have to buy a each machine a license. Not exactly what im looking for but still a pretty sweet program. Thanks Techie007

Comment: No, you don't have to buy it for each machine, just for the number of machine for that month.  So say 20 machines a week * 4 weeks a month = ~80 machines/month.  1-100 machines is $20/month.  they are also lenient with their limits as well. :)

Comment: From https://ninite.com/pro#plans FAQ: "How does the licensing work if I repair different computers all the time? -- The machine count resets every 30 days. We designed it this way so it would work for computer repair shops. Just pick the plan that matches your monthly volume."